# Writing a replacement "App Launcher" / "Home Screen" for iPad

Tags: ipad, ios5

Is there a way for schools and businesses to replace the iPad "app launcher" or "home screen" with a customized alternative?

Could an application be developed for iOS that would allow this? Or is the SDK locked down to prevent such an application from being developed.

All pointers and insights greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are apps like this on Absynthe, maybe you could look into those? Some may even be open source

Comment: What kind of alternative are you thinking about?

Comment: @TheEdge, your question isn't getting much attention, and i think my answer is valid, so could you either update your question, or accept my answer. Let me know what other information you would like.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the load screen, from the dark black to an image ,but no you can't change the layout of the app menu on the iOSDevice. At least not without jail-braking. This is because apple doesn't want you editing their menu that gives them a nice clean look, or see their software.

The app-launcher is not part of the app, it's different even though it's still mainly made with cocoa in objective c, it's still not accessible by you, legally. So since I frown upon jailbraking, and I'm pretty sure most developers do, I would advise to focus on your app, not the main menu which already works great.

Check out ana [App launcher definition here.](http://gizmodo.com/5920312/what-is-an-app-launcher)

---

The sdk is completely locked down, but you could still make a big app, like an app box that has multiple apps inside. The application could be web-based, allowing more access without updating the app, meaning no waiting for apple to approve an update.

One more alternative is that you could make custom apps that are free, and easy for the students or whoever to download them, but they would require a student password to unlock.

**Don't edit an OS, it could do serious damage to the device software forever.**

Comment: About your last sentence - "it could do serious damage to the device software forever" - can't you just restore the device to fix it if you "edit the OS"?

Comment: @qegal no, evidence shows, that after jail-braking a little bit of the code stays on the iOSDevice. Also the device stores if it has been jailbroken so that the apple warranty brakes, and they are no longer responsible. Jail brake code stays on your device, what do you expect, it's technically a super virus.